# How to make connection into secure websocket server using authorization credentials in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, web-services

How can I make a secure (TLS) websocket client connection using Faye-websocket in Ruby?

I am using faye/websocket gem in my script.

The question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801789/secure-websocket-client-in-ruby).
but it was not replied properly.

```
#!/bin/sh ruby

require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('wss://socket.myexample.com/',['irc', 'amqp'],
  :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic ZmFybWxhbmQ6c2FyYWk3OTQ='})

  ws.on :open do |event|
    ws.send('getAssetList')
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    p [:message, event.data]
  end

  ws.on :error do |event|
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
   p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
   ws = nil
  end
}
```

It returns me the following response.

```
errorCode:8
expiry:"2016-05-17T08:04:24.704Z"
ghostId:"6f38e205-7d36-4146-9fb9-3776e4fcabff"
message:"Please login"
passwordPolicy:null
serverTime:"2016-05-17T07:44:24.704Z"
sessionPolicy:null
user:null
```

Comment: Did you find a solution @user1724991?